# From PA to Location Audio or Sound Designer

Tags: location-audio, location

I just received a phone call asking for my availability to work on my first MAJOR feature film as a production assistant. Normally, when I think of PAs, those are the guys wrangling extras or actors, securing the set, breaking it down and such. When I sent in my resume and cover letter for this position, I highlighted my training in location audio and Audio post production.

I then spoke about how I may be able to assist the location audio team (preparing file names on 744T recorders, for example). In addition to being on time and being a hard and efficient worker, I would like any advice on perhaps getting into a Union for location audio in the future.

More importantly, however, are there PAs that are attached to the Audio team only? Part of me feels like I just made that position up.

PS - I should add that I did read the Wiki on Production Assistants. So I do have a general idea of what they do. But I was wondering if any had worked as a PA in their transition to becoming a sound designer or to work in Audio Post production... in fact, I think i'll change the heading.

Comment: Hi Tks very much for post: I like it and hope that you continue posting. Let me show other source that may be good for community. Source: [production assistant cover letter](http://coverlettersamples.biz/cover-letter-sample-for-production-assistant) Best rgs
David

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, PA is just a synonym for "grunt." You can be a PA in almost any role in film production.

I was an audio post PA on a major feature...just the title they gave me since I wasn't union yet. But that was on the post side of things, assisting the Supervising Sound Editor, Sound Editors, and Assistant Sound Editors. Although working in that role was pretty menial sometimes (LA traffic stinks), I did get the opportunity to shadow some seasoned pros, learn how to be a proper Assistant Sound Editor, and they even allowed me to cut fx on a couple sequences. It did lead to better roles in film down the line...although it was a major (but temporary) step back for me considering I had worked as a sound designer for TV commercials for a number of years before I took the position on.

I think it'd be much more difficult to transition into audio post if you're assisting production sound though. The production mixer is usually off to their next job before audio post even starts. Find out who's doing the audio post on your film and try to get a gig with them. Really the best, if not only, way to get into Post. If you're hard working and loyal, they'll most likely call you for their next gig and maybe even assist you in getting in to the sound editors union.

Comment: That's amazing advice I read here :) That's pretty much the answer to the thread I started this afternoon!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both of you for the great question and great answer...

Kurt